# Importing snapdragon in android studio

Tags: android, import

I have an external jar that I need to import into my project as a lib. The thing is, it also includes libfacialproc_jni.so which I'm assuming is a config file. Anyways I copied both the jar and the libfacialproc_jni.so in the libs folder but it seems to have an issue grabbing the libfacialproc_jni.so. This is the error: 01-18 20:51:49.917 16903-16903/trashometer.adrenapps.main.trashometer E/Facial_Processing: Failed to load facialproc_jni. Make sure that libfacialproc_jni.so is included in your project.

I switched to android studio recently unfortunately from eclipse where in eclipse i did the same thing put both files in libs folder and no issues. But in android studio I'm having issues. I'm totally new to android studio so I have no idea where to start, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. You place the jar in the libs folder but the .so file you make a directory in the src/main folder and call it jniLibs and that's it! I'm using android 1.5 just to let you know so this may not work for all android studio versions.